# pfsense xml restore on dissimilar hardware

Tags: pfsense, backup-restoration

pfsense has it's built in backup and restore function. it stores backup in xml files. they are located in /cf/config directory. backup can be done in many was from web interface or from directories. I want to ask if anyone has restored xml backup on fresh installed pfsense with dissimilar hardware and what kind of problems did you encountered, and what can you suggest to change in xml file before restore.

thanks :)

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve? What hardware are you migrating to? Have you tested this restore?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have done this many times. PfSense will ask you to correct the interfaces if the interfaces don't matchup. I typically just edit the xml config before restoring, sometimes it just easier.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. Edited xml that match new hardware